# Object doesn't support this property or method - JQUERY - IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am using Jquery 1.5 to manipulate a form, I have been recieving the following error in IE 7

```
Object doesn't support this property or methood
Line: 10, Char: 0
```

I am using the following code:

```
Line 8:   $(':input[name=firstname], :input[name=lastname], :input[name=middlename]').blur(function(){
Line 9:     var fullName = $(':input[name=firstname]').val().trim() + " " + $(':input[name=middlename]').val().trim() + " " + $(':input[name=lastname]').val().trim();
Line 10:    $(':input[name=sys_title], :input[name=displaytitle]').val(fullName);
Line: 11: });
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would fail in IE7 and not in FF?

Thanks

Comment: Might help to see some HTML or even better, a jsFiddle

Comment: Why the colon infront of input in your selector?

Comment: I used the colons to indicate the line

Comment: @MottiHoresh I meant in your selector `:input[name=sys_title]`, why the colon?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson That is the form selector to select any form element.

Comment: @MottiHoresh I might be on thin ice here, but why use it compared to the tag selector $("input") which I believe would be more performant, since it is a native CSS selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IE7, I think blur event won't work, you'll have to handle something like :

```
$('input[name=firstname]').bind('focusout', function(){
    alert('focusout');
});
```

You got more info in JQuery page :

`The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).`

Comment: I would think so as Jquery got a method for that : http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 1):

[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) doesn't work that way.

`$(':input[name=firstname]').val().trim()` won't work.

`$.trim($(':input[name=firstname]').val())` **will work**.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be the problem.